# In IE11 opacity value remains 0 untill mouse over on the element

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I have created a table, for some cells I have applied opacity value 0.30. its works fine in all browser except `ie11` alone browser.opacity value remains 0 until I mouse over on the element. I have tried `filter:alpha(opacity=30)` also but does not work.
I have used following  css to apply opacity for td which have class "disable"

```
td.disable
{
opacity:0.30;
filter:alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

above styles works fine in all browser except ie11 alone browser.thanks for any advice

Comment: You need to post some code in your question, preferably with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate your problem

Comment: Try to add `zoom` like `zoom:1;`

Comment: thanks for update.I have tried with zoom also but its does not work